# Can mode='wb' in python I/O operations write image binaries

Tags: python, python-requests, python-3.9

[see my pc screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfXqZ.jpg)
the piece of code I used is this:

```
from wikipedia import page
import requests

responce = requests.get(page('beach').images[0])

with open(r'files/beach.jpg', mode='wb') as file:
    file.write(responce.content)
```

but it always endup making a file which photo viewer can not open

> python version 3.9.6, modules installed wikipedia:1.4.0, requests:2.26.0

it is running perfectly fine on my machine without any error

Comment: changing image file extension to .png or any other format did not solve the problem either

Comment: DId you check the error code of the request? I tried running your code, and I got a 403 error, and the response content was an HTML error page.

Comment: @rchome it is not showing me any such erroe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if the below code works as per your requirement. The problem with your code is that you are just writing the raw content of the Wikipedia HTML page to  **files/beach.jpg** file in binary mode and it isn't a valid image file. To understand better, try renaming the image file created by your earlier code to `beach.txt` and see the content.

```
from wikipedia import page
from urllib.request import urlretrieve

urlretrieve(page('beach').images[0], "files/beach.jpg")
```

Comment: To clarify further if you open the files/beach.jpg with a text editor you should see it starting with `<!DOCTYPE html>` so it's not an image.

Comment: I am really thankful for your help, actually I saw a tutorial online and he was doing it the way I had done, but somehow his code worked.